# Browser stop working when the Range slider moves

Tags: jquery, html, browser

This is my HTML markup:

```
<input type="button" value="one" id="btnOne"><br/>
<input type="range" class="rangeSliderOne" min="1" max="5" id="DR" name="DROne" value="0" />
 <input type="button" value="two" id="btnTwo"><br/>
 <input type="checkbox" value="one" id="chkBox" ><br/>
 <input type="text" value="test" id="txtBox" style="display:none" > <br/>
```

And the jQuery code used for this:

```
$('#btnOne').prop('disabled', true);
$('#DR').change(function() {
    $('#btnOne').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#DR').attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
});

$('#chkBox').click(function() {
    $("#txtBox").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

When the range change. the browser stops working.

Please help me to find the solution thank you...  This error only showing in Chrome browse. 
http://jsfiddle.net/XNyMj/

Answer (score 1):

The browser doesn't stop working, but you are disabling the input range slider on change event of the slider moving. Therefore the slider becomes disabled

Comment: :Actually i wanna disable my range slider on the change event. when the range slider change the browser get stuck. this issue only on chrome browser. do the following step on google chrome. >>Change the range slider. >> then inspect the elements of the the chrome browser. >>we can't do anything on the google Chrome Browser after Change Event.Why that happening?